# MySQL/NodeJS- How to adopt first in - last out system? + how to shadow table

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, node.js

I need to make sure table contains only 200 rows.
Say starting with ID 1 ending with ID 200.
When record with ID 201 is added, record with ID 1 is removed. So there is always 200 rows. Kind of like stack.

I am using NodeJS +SocketIO + MySQL.
So how would I go about doing this? Can I somehow setup a trigger or something in phpMyAdmin?

Also how can I shadow table? So that table #2 keeps ALL records not just 200 of them like table #1. 
But: table #2 is located on different server in different database. 
Any way to setup trigger on phpMyAdmin as well for this?

Comment: Why not just use one table and then just SELECT the last 200 entries (e.g. `SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 200`)?

Comment: I know I could do that, but is there any specific way to do what I want?